# How can get timer from asynctask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Cant access the time in AsyncTask, the variable `point` doesn't change anymore

Here is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class GamePlayActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Player> arrPlayer = new ArrayList<Player>();
    TextView tvLevel, tvPoint;
    ImageView ivGuessedImage;
    Button btn1stChoice, btn2ndChoice, btn3rdChoice, btn4thChoice;
    int level = 1;
    int point = 0;
    Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    ProgressBar customProgress;
    TextView progressDisplay;
    int myProgress;
    MediaPlayer mp1, mp2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_gameplayactivity);

        mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(GamePlayActivity.this, R.raw.uefa_champion_league);
        mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(GamePlayActivity.this, R.raw.the_time_of_our_life);
        mp1.start();
        mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp2.start();
            }
        });
        mp2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp1.start();
            }
        });


        tvLevel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLevel);
        tvPoint = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPoint);
        ivGuessedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivGuessedImage);
        btn1stChoice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1stChoice);
        btn2ndChoice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2ndChoice);
        btn3rdChoice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3rdChoice);
        btn4thChoice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4thChoice);

        arrPlayer = createPlayer();
        Collections.shuffle(arrPlayer);
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(arrPlayer.get(0).getPlayerFile(), "drawable", getPackageName());
        ivGuessedImage.setImageResource(resID);
        btn1stChoice.setText(arrPlayer.get(0).getPlayerName());
        btn2ndChoice.setText(arrPlayer.get(1).getPlayerName());
        btn3rdChoice.setText(arrPlayer.get(2).getPlayerName());
        btn4thChoice.setText(arrPlayer.get(3).getPlayerName());

        customProgress = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.customProgress);
        progressDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.progressDisplay);
        new ShowCustomProgressBarAsyncTask().execute();
        if(myProgress < 1){
            Intent intent = new Intent(GamePlayActivity.this, GameOverActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        btn1stChoice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (btn1stChoice.getText().toString() == arrPlayer.get(0).getPlayerName()) {
                    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(GamePlayActivity.this, R.raw.right_answer);
                    mp.start();
                    point = point + 2;
                    tvPoint.setText(point + " Point");
                    createNewLevel();
                    myProgress = 100;
                } else {
                    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(GamePlayActivity.this, R.raw.wrong_answer);
                    mp.start();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(GamePlayActivity.this, GameOverActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Point", point);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

        btn2ndChoice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(btn2ndChoice.getText().toString() == arrPlayer.get(0).getPlayerName()){
                    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(GamePlayActivity.this, R.raw.right_answer);
                    mp.start();
                    point = point + 2;
                    tvPoint.setText(point + " Point");
                    createNewLevel();
                    myProgress = 100;
                }
                else{
                    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(GamePlayActivity.this, R.raw.wrong_answer);
                    mp.start();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(GamePlayActivity.this, GameOverActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Point", point);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

        btn3rdChoice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(btn3rdChoice.getText().toString() == arrPlayer.get(0).getPlayerName()){
                    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(GamePlayActivity.this, R.raw.right_answer);
                    mp.start();
                    point = point + 2;
                    tvPoint.setText(point + " Point");
                    createNewLevel();
                    myProgress = 100;
                }
                else{
                    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(GamePlayActivity.this, R.raw.wrong_answer);
                    mp.start();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(GamePlayActivity.this, GameOverActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Point", point);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

        btn4thChoice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(btn4thChoice.getText().toString() == arrPlayer.get(0).getPlayerName()){
                    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(GamePlayActivity.this, R.raw.right_answer);
                    mp.start();
                    point = point + 2;
                    tvPoint.setText(point + " Point");
                    createNewLevel();
                    myProgress = 100;
                }
                else{
                    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(GamePlayActivity.this, R.raw.wrong_answer);
                    mp.start();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(GamePlayActivity.this, GameOverActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Point", point);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public class ShowCustomProgressBarAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            myProgress = 100;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            while(myProgress>0){
                myProgress--;
                publishProgress(myProgress);
                SystemClock.sleep(200);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            customProgress.setProgress(values[0]);
            customProgress.setSecondaryProgress(values[0] + 1);
            progressDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(myProgress)+"%");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        }
    }

    public void createNewLevel(){
        arrPlayer.remove(0);
        Collections.shuffle(arrPlayer);
        int randomButtonChoice = rand.nextInt(4);
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(arrPlayer.get(0).getPlayerFile(), "drawable", getPackageName());
        ((BitmapDrawable)ivGuessedImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
        ivGuessedImage.setImageResource(resID);
        switch (randomButtonChoice){
            case 0: {
                btn1stChoice.setText(arrPlayer.get(0).getPlayerName());
                btn2ndChoice.setText(arrPlayer.get(1).getPlayerName());
                btn3rdChoice.setText(arrPlayer.get(2).getPlayerName());
                btn4thChoice.setText(arrPlayer.get(3).getPlayerName());

                break;
            }
            case 1: {
                btn1stChoice.setText(arrPlayer.get(1).getPlayerName());
                btn2ndChoice.setText(arrPlayer.get(0).getPlayerName());
                btn3rdChoice.setText(arrPlayer.get(2).getPlayerName());
                btn4thChoice.setText(arrPlayer.get(3).getPlayerName());

                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                btn1stChoice.setText(arrPlayer.get(1).getPlayerName());
                btn2ndChoice.setText(arrPlayer.get(2).getPlayerName());
                btn3rdChoice.setText(arrPlayer.get(0).getPlayerName());
                btn4thChoice.setText(arrPlayer.get(3).getPlayerName());

                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                btn1stChoice.setText(arrPlayer.get(1).getPlayerName());
                btn2ndChoice.setText(arrPlayer.get(2).getPlayerName());
                btn3rdChoice.setText(arrPlayer.get(3).getPlayerName());
                btn4thChoice.setText(arrPlayer.get(0).getPlayerName());

                break;
            }
        }
        level++;
        tvLevel.setText("Level " + level);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I personally don't understand what is your problem and what are you asking for... You should get values from the AsyncTask in the onProgressUpdate, that's it.

Comment: I cant get the myProgress value, when I set OnClickListener, I want to asign the a = a * myProgress, but it doesn't asigned, the ProgressBar countdown from 100 to 0. For example, it run at 82, I want the a = 82.

Comment: You want to get the progress into `a` variable when it reaches a particular value. right?

Comment: That's exactly what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with an interface

create an interface in your `AsyncTask`, and create a method which will be used as the callback

```
 public class ShowCustomProgressBarAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    interface ProgressListner {
        public void onProgressChanged(int progress);
    }
    private ProgressListner listner;
    public ShowCustomProgressBarAsyncTask(ProgressListner listner) {
        this.listner = listner;
    }
    //..your remaining codes

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        //..your remaining codes
        listner.onProgressChanged(values[0]);
    }
 }
```

Then implement that interface in your activity.

Also pass an instance of the interface through the constructor to the `AsyncTask`.

Then using that instance you can callback a method which will pass the progress value

```
 public class GamePlayActivity extends Activity implements ProgressListner{
    //.. your remaining codes

    new ShowCustomProgressBarAsyncTask(this).execute();

    public void onProgressChanged(int progress) {
        a = progress;
    }
 }
```

Comment: The ProgressBar doesnt countdown and how can setOnClickListener to asign a = progress?

Comment: But, when I do with your way, the ProgressBar doesn't countdown anymore

Comment: The variable a not change, I have just try

Comment: Did you implemented the interface correctly, can you post the code?

Comment: If you want the progress value out of the `AsyncTask` its better to use an interface, if you implemented it correctly it will work.

Comment: One question more, when the progress come down to 0, it's not asigned to 100 again or Intent to another Activity